# Yii2 rest api rewrite rules

Tags: php, rest, url-rewriting, yii2, restful-url

This is how my url manager looks like:

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl'     => true,
    'enableStrictParsing' => true,
    'showScriptName'      => false,
    'rules' => [
        [
            'class'         => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
            'pluralize'     => false,
            'controller'    => 'v1/user',
            'extraPatterns' => [
                'GET account' => 'account',
            ],
        ]
    ],
]
```

In order to make this call I can access this url:

`localhost/project/api/web/v1/user/account`

What I need to do is to remove controller name from url(user). I need to call the api at this url:

`localhost/project/api/web/v1/account`.

How can I achieve this? I tried a lot of tricks but none worked.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add following expression under rules

```
'v1/account' => 'v1/user/account',
```

Comment: Thx a lot, it works. It was much easier than I taught :).